# Mongodb authentication issue when using same volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, nosql, volume

I am using mongo db in the docker container. I am using docker compose to spin up mongo. Now we have old mongo containers running and authentication is not enforced. In order to use authentication enforced and start up script I am using .env filein my docker compose file as below. But .env file and startup script are taking place only if I change the volume. By using same volume both .env file and startup script is not taking any effect. Is there any way to use the same volume and create users using .env and also use start up script.

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongot
    restart: always
    env_file:
  - .env
    ports:
  - 27019:27017
    volumes:
  - /data/db8/configdb:/data/configdb
  - /data/db8/db:/data/db
  - $PWD/mongoentry/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    network_mode: "bridge"
    command: mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment files and startup scripts are only used when creating a new database. If a database already exists, they aren't used.

In your case, you already have a database in the volume, so they aren't used. But if you change the volume so no database exists, Mongo creates a new one using your values and scripts.

From the docs:

> When you start the mongo image, you can adjust the initialization of
> the MongoDB instance by passing one or more environment variables on
> the docker run command line. Do note that none of the variables below
> will have any effect if you start the container with a data directory
> that already contains a database

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to create users in the run time and enforce authentication using docker. As I guess for existing containers to enforce authentication manually logging and create users is the only solution I can think of right now if not for env/startup script.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But you can create users in an existing Mongo database like you'd normally do.